# Hibernate DB2 Dialect Pagination Issue

Tags: hibernate, db2, dialect

We are using DB2 Database with Hibernate Db2 Dialect which is not working with Server side Pagination. It is working fine for first first page but not for other pages.

I am getting this error information Caused by:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
>   SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=OF;( . AT MICROSECONDS
>   MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND MINUTES MINUTE, DRIVER=4.19.26

We are using Hibernate 5 with JPA 2.1 version. We are using orderby criteria which generates a hql query like below

```
select * from 
( select inner2_.*, rownumber() over(order by order of inner2_) as rownumber_ 
from
( select id as id_,name as name_ from employee as employee_ where employee_.name="employee1" order by employee_.id fetch first 2 rows only ) 
as inner2_) 
as inner1_  where rownumber_ > 1 order by rownumber_;
```

I tried the same query with SQLServer  and it is working with out any issues.

Comment: I am getting  this error information Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=OF;( . AT MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND MINUTES MINUTE, DRIVER=4.19.26

Comment: What platform and version of Db2 are you using? `fetch first x rows only` in a sub-select is not supported in some versions.

Comment: It's your job to determine exactly which *version* and *platform variant* of Db2-server you are using. This determines whether the dialect should be org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect or org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect.    This is a FAQ.

Comment: @JavaBackendDeveloper Did you find any solution for this problem?